# Why is this nested lambda not considered constexpr?

Tags: c++, lambda, metaprogramming, c++17, boost-hana

I'm trying to create a curried interface using nested constexpr lambdas, but the compiler does not consider it to be a constant expression.

```
namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

struct C1 {};

template < typename T,
           std::size_t size >
struct Array {};

constexpr auto array_ = [] (auto size) {
      return [=] (auto type) {
        return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size()>>;
      };
    };

int main() {

  constexpr auto c1 = hana::type_c<C1>;
  constexpr auto test = hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(c1)::type, hana::size_c<100>()>>;
  constexpr auto test2 = array_(hana::size_c<100>)(c1);
}
```

I post a question earlier because I found a different minimal example, but it wasn't enough.

**Error:**

```
test2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘<lambda(auto:1)>::<lambda(auto:2)> [with auto:2 = boost::hana::type_impl<C1>::_; auto:1 = boost::hana::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 100>]’:
test2.cpp:31:54:   required from here
test2.cpp:20:16: error: ‘__closure’ is not a constant expression
         return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size()>>;
                ^~~~
test2.cpp:20:16: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’ 
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test2.cpp:31:18: error: ‘constexpr const void test2’ has incomplete type
   constexpr auto test2 = array_(hana::size_c<100>)(c1);
```

`__closure is not a constant expression` : if someone could explain me this error that would be a great help. I ran into that error before but can't remember why.

Comment: A lambda that captures a non-constexpr value is not constexpr. In this case `size` is a non-constexpr function parameter. There is a simple workaround for this. Ask why the result of the lambda call is not constexpr and maybe they will unflag it.

Comment: @NathanOlivier I believe this question is more specific than "Is constexpr lambda supported", plus it addresses a common pitfall with this type of metaprogramming.

Comment: @JasonRice Do you mean that hana::size_c<100> "lost" it's constexpr because of the lambda capture? I'm going to sleep a little and I'll check if I can find this workaround, tanks :)

Comment: It's not constexpr because it is a function parameter. Since it is stateless and default constructible you can do `constexpr auto size_ = decltype(size){};` or use a type alias and have it in the context of the nested lambda without capture `Size{}` which is better. Note that having everything constexpr upfront isn't always necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to odr-use one of a lambda's captured variables in a template non-type argument.

```
  return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size()>>;
//                                                         ^~~~
```

A template non-type argument must be a constant expression. Inside a lambda, you can't odr-use a captured variable in a constant expression. Whether or not the lambda is `constexpr` is irrelevant.

But you can odr-use ordinary variables in constant expressions, even if they are not `constexpr` variables. For example, this is legal:

```
std::integral_constant<int, 100> i; // i is not constexpr
std::array<int, i()> a; // using i in a constant expression
```

So why can't we odr-use captured variables in constant expressions? I don't know the motivation for this rule, but here it is in the standard:

> [expr.const]
>
> (¶2) A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless...
>   (¶2.11) in a *lambda-expression*, a reference to `this` or to a variable with automatic storage duration defined outside that *lambda-expression*, where the reference would be an odr-use.

[CWG1613](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1613) may hold some clue.

If we were to rewrite the inner lambda as a named class, we would have a different but related problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct Closure {
  T size;
  constexpr Closure(T size_) : size(size_) {}

  template <typename U>
  constexpr auto operator()(U type) const {
    return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size()>>;
  }
};
constexpr auto array_ = [] (auto size) {
  return Closure { size };
};
```

Now the error would be the implicit use of the `this` pointer in a template non-type argument.

```
  return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size()>>;
//                                                         ^~~~~
```

I declared `Closure::operator()()` as a `constexpr` function for consistency, but that is immaterial. The `this` pointer is forbidden to be used in a constant expression ([expr.const] ¶2.1). Functions declared `constexpr` do not get special dispensation to relax the rules for the constant expressions that may appear within them.

Now the original error makes a little bit more sense, because captured variables are transformed into data members of the lambda's closure type, so using captured variables is a little bit like indirecting through the lambda's own "`this` pointer".

This is the workaround that introduces the least alteration to the code:

```
constexpr auto array_ = [] (auto size) {
  return [=] (auto type) {
    const auto size_ = size;
    return hana::type_c<Array<typename decltype(type)::type, size_()>>;
  };
};
```

Now we are using the captured variable outside of a constant expression, to initialize an ordinary variable which we can then use in the template non-type argument.

This answer has been edited a few times, so the comments below may reference previous revisions.

Comment: Are you sure it is not implementation-defined whether `integral_constant::operator()` performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `*this`? If so, then this answer is the correct one and my answer is wrong.

Comment: @LouisDionne I wasn't able to find any indication that it might apply the L2R conversion. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. But I am rethinking other parts of my answer. I think I misunderstood integral constant expression. I think that where gcc and clang differ is on whether or not the lambda odr-uses `size`.

Comment: @LouisDionne I think I figured it out now, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I reduced your test case to this:

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr auto f = [](auto size) {
  return [=](){
    constexpr auto s = size();
    return 1;
  };
};

static_assert(f(std::integral_constant<int, 100>{})(), "");

int main() { }
```

As said in the comments above, this happens because `size` is not a constant expression from within the function body. This is not specific to Hana. As a workaround, you can use

```
constexpr auto f = [](auto size) {
  return [=](){
    constexpr auto s = decltype(size)::value;
    return 1;
  };
};
```

or anything similar.

Comment: I'm interrested by this behavior, do you know where I can find some information on this? Why it's a function parameter means that it's not constexpr?

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel Boost.Hana's manual has an appendix on this: http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-appendix-constexpr