# Clang compile error related to static_assert and boost::hana

Tags: c++, clang++, static-assert, boost-hana

Consider the following problem which compiles successfully on Clang 3.8 using `-std=c++14`.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    constexpr auto indices = hana::range<unsigned, 0, 3>();
    hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto i) {
        hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto j) {
            constexpr bool test = (i == (j == i ? j : i));
            static_assert(test, "error");
        });
    });
}
```

The test is quite non-sensical but that is not the point. Consider now an alternative version where the test is directly put inside the `static_assert`:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    constexpr auto indices = hana::range<unsigned, 0, 3>();
    hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto i) {
        hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto j) {
            static_assert((i == (j == i ? j : i)), "error");
        });
    });
}
```

Now I get a bunch of compile errors, saying

> error: reference to local variable `i` declared in enclosing lambda expression

**Question: What causes the second version to fail?**

*Edit: Could this be a compiler bug? I turns out that when accessing `i` before the `static_assert`, everything compiles again:*

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    constexpr auto indices = hana::range<unsigned, 0, 3>();
    hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto i) {
        hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto j) {
            constexpr auto a = i;
            static_assert((i == (j == i ? j : i)), "error");
        });
    });
}
```

*Update: The same behaviour can be reproduced on Clang 4.0 and the current development branch 5.0.*

*Update 2: As suggested by @LouisDionne, I filed this as a bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33318.*

Comment: @aschepler: Sorry - I don't get your point. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: "this" is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665610/why-is-this-nested-lambda-not-considered-constexpr

Comment: I _believe_ that is a compiler bug. I think your best bet is to file a bug against Clang and see what the knowledgeable folks over there think.

Comment: @LouisDionne - thanks for the suggestion. It got acknowledged as a bug in Clang.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the bug in an answer to your own question so it can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Clang compiler and was acknowledged as such. Here is the link to it: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33318.