# clang vs gcc: variadic lambda captures

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

I am trying to capture a variadic lambda argument inside a inner lambda and use it there.
As an example, consider this code:

```cpp
int main () {
    auto first = [&] (auto&&... one) {
        auto second = [&] (auto&&... two) {
            return ((one * two) + ...);
        };
        return second(one...);
    };
    return first(5);
}
```

This works with gcc9 but fails with clang8 (https://godbolt.org/z/i2K9cK).

A way to make the code compile is to explicitly capture `[&one...]`, but i was wondering whether this is a bug in clang.

Also interesting: Changing the return statement to something where `one` is directly expanded (before combining with `two`), this compiles again:
`return (((one * ...) * two) + ...);`

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355720/clang-compile-error-related-to-static-assert-and-boosthana) related post, but the bug declared there seems to be fixed in clang8.

Comment: The fact that this compiles with `return (((one * ...) * two) + ...);` but fails with a *"error: reference to local variable 'one' declared in enclosing lambda expression"* without strongly suggests a bug in `clang`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Clang. It has been [reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42104).  Per [comment](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42104#c1):

> Fixed in r362358.

(Side note: Clang seems to have difficulty with pack-expansions in captures in general. Let's roll out our own version of the closure type generated for the generic lambda `first`:

```
struct __closure_first {
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... one) const
    {
        auto second = [&] (auto&&... two) {
            return ((one * two) + ...);
        };
        return second(one...);
    }
};
```

Clearly, this is not a real closure type, and non-closure local classes cannot have member function templates. Putting this in the global scope, [GCC still works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9RAfGsPtpXMbrDPR) and [Clang still fails](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hKfYKguOlyPBG0K4).)