# gcc vs clang: expanding a captured parameter pack twice

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang

Consider this code snippet:

```
int main () {
    auto first = [&] (auto... one) {
        auto faulty = [&] () {
            [[maybe_unused]] auto i = (one + ...);
            return (one + ...);
        };
        faulty();
    };
    first(1);
}
```

See also [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4WWoym).

It seems that when I try to expand the implicitly captured parameter pack `one` twice inside the inner lambda, gcc complains, but clang does not.
Note that when I explicitly capture, like so `[&one...]`, gcc doesn't complain anymore.

To me this looks like a gcc bug, but I would like some confirmation from people who are more experienced than me, since I have already seen (different) buggy behaviour in clang with variadic captures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356708/clang-vs-gcc-variadic-lambda-captures).

Comment: How is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356708/clang-vs-gcc-variadic-lambda-captures?

Comment: 1. gcc complains here, clang complained before
2. it occurs in different scenarios
3. the compiler error is different.

The only thing that is identical is that `[&one...]` seems to fix it :D

Comment: I suggest that you link to your previous question and explain the difference because they are similar. Otherwise people who have saw your previous question (like me) may be confused.

Comment: i assume these are quite different, but alright

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP has clarified that this is not a repost of the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in GCC 9. It has been [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90538).

GCC 8 compiles the code [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CE7vMA6ZnwsrJEtY).